# Using DigitalOcean droplet/vserver with ISPConfig3 - access the sites by IP

Tags: cpanel, cloud-hosting, digital-ocean

My problem is that I'd like to be able to use temporary urls for my sites that are still in development phase. With cPanel i had this option:

- create a new account (choose username, pass, etc.)
- that account is assigned an IP
- list all my accounts in the WHM, then click the IP showing for the account in question
- a new tab opens, showing in the address bar sth like this: `http://85.65.342.388/~username`

That works just fine for my needs. So I wonder if something like that is possible having set up the following:

- Digital Ocean cloud hosting - droplet created on Ubuntu
- Installed Ispconfig3 to manage the server
- one (not sure if single) server IP

I can visit my server IP - it opens the test website I uploaded to /var/www of the server when I just started testing the server (prior to installing Ispconfig)

Paths to my newly created accounts are:

```
/var/www/clients/client1/web1
/var/www/clients/client1/web2
/var/www/clients/client2/web1
etc...
```

Should I be able to access for example the website having its files in /var/www/clients/client1/web2 in a way that is similar to the above cPanel example?

There is an option in the Ispconfig to add server IPs but I'm unsure how to add them - because my droplet is showing a single IP and I don't see any spots to add additional IPs (in my Digital Ocean account interface).

Also my accounts (sites) have the option to select from predefined IP addresses (select box) but they come with only asterisk (*) shown as default.

Trying to set up new IP addresses via Ispconfig and then selecting one of them from Site's settings didn't help - nothing opens by visiting such an IP.